# what programming should i do in Moodle?

Tags: web, moodle

I am creating a CMS for my university as a project using moodle.I have installed moodle and XAMPP server.

Now I see that moodle already has everything I want.There is nothing I should do now except for adding courses , users and managing permissions etc which any lay man can do. Is this correct or am I missing anything? It is enough if I add courses and users (students and teachers) . And this does not need any programming. Am i right?

Comment: You are right, welcome to Moodle :) You might want to look through the Moodle wiki too http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/Main_page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you're right. For the tasks you cited, the Moodle web interface will be fine.

Comment: I see that you're pretty new to StackOverflow. In this community when you're grateful about an answer you can upvote it, and if you find that it resolved your problem, you can mark it as the accepted answer. Anyway, you're welcome :)